# Scala RDD[(String,String)] to RDD[String]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

We are reading a file in UTF_8 as RDD[(String,String)],  Need help in converting this to RDD[String].

```
val textRdd = sparkSession.sparkContext.binaryFiles(filePath,12)
     .mapValues(content => new String(content.toArray(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to extract value from tuple i.e (string, string).

```
val outRDD = textRdd.map(t=>t._2) // To get first value use t._1
```